# looping over databases and doing mysql query execution...will it wait until query is done?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php
foreach($databases as $database)
{
    system("mysql --host=$db_host --user=$db_user --password=$db_password -v -v -v $database < ../update.sql"); 
}
?>
```

My questions is: Will the code wait (it appears to) before executing the update.sql for each database? I don't want to spawn a ton of queries at once. I just want to do them 1 by 1.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you need to query the db like this? Could you not just use a pure PHP/MySQL based implementation ?

Comment: as written. it'll wait. but there's better ways of doing this that doesn't involve firing up shells and passing in potentially "bad" filenames, or leaving credentials in your shell's command history.

Comment: This is for an upgrade script on many databases with same schema. This is not a public script; only run from cli on db server. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) says on [this functions manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php):

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Comment: So since I am not redirecting output it will hang right? Also since it is cli it shouldn't timeout right? (Max execution)

Comment: yes, and if your calling the script from the command line - then yes no timeout issues.